# Asp.net C# Highlight matching Gridview label text from textbox multiple words

Tags: c#, gridview, match

When a values is entered in the text box then the values that matches with the content of the GridView should be highlighted. I am able to achieve this with single word but when I use multiple words in the text box then it does not work. Any help would be much appreciated. Below is my C# code behind :

```
 foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)                   //loop each row
     {
                    Label lblDescription = gvr.FindControl("lblDescription") as Label;                       
    
                    lblDescription.Text = Regex.Replace(lblDescription.Text, txtSearch.Text.Trim(), delegate (Match match)
                    {
                        return string.Format("<span style = 'background-color:#f30a31'>{0}</span>", match.Value);
                    }, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);        
                   
    }
```

Comment: You should split the `txtSearch.Text` by space, so that you get array of words. Then loop thru array of word and use RegEx.Replace for each of the words in the loop.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you for your idea, it worked with little effort. I am posting the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)                   //loop each row
     {                    
                Label lblDescription = gvr.FindControl("lblDescription") as Label;      
                string searchtext = txtSearch.Text;
                string[] searchtextList = searchtext.Split(' ');
                foreach (string textlist in searchtextList)
                {    
                    lblDescription.Text = Regex.Replace(lblDescription.Text, textlist.Trim(), delegate (Match match)
                    {
                        return string.Format("<span style = 'background-color:#ee953f'>{0}</span>", match.Value);
                    }, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                }                    
    }
```